# Python 3.3.2 Cosine Rule Unknown Angle

Tags: python, rule, trigonometry

What I currently have is

```
 x = float(input("Side opposite unknown angle: "))
 y = float(input("Second Side: "))
 z = float(input("Third Side: "))

 print ("Angle is: "+str((x**2+y**2-z**2)/2*x*y)*math.acos)
```

And the error I receive is

```
print ("Angle is: "+str((x**2+y**2-z**2)/2*x*y)*math.acos)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("Angle is: "+str((x**2+y**2-z**2)/2*x*y)*math.acos)
```

should be

```
print ("Angle is: "+str(math.acos((y**2+z**2-x**2)/(2*y*z)))
```

Notice where the parenthesis are.

Problems:

1. `math.acos` is a function that should be invoked.
2. Arguments of `str` should include the result of `math.acos`
3. You're using the wrong variables in the equation.

Comment: i have now got the error "ValueError: math domain error"

Comment: @xMutiiNy acos is only defined for arguments between -1 and 1 (inclusive). Try `print( (y**2 + z**2 = x**2)/2*y*z )` to check that that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `math.acos` with `math.acos((x/360.0)*2*math.pi)` if `x` is in degrees or just `math.acos(x)` if `x` is in radians. Also move it within the call to `str`.